# Uniform Distribution / Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Let the random variable X ~ U ( 0, k ) and Y is a second random variable such as
Y | X ~ N ( X , 1).
a) Determine the Y density function if k = A .
b) Determine the value of k if COV [X , Y ] = B.

a)
So I started with this:

The density function of a uniform distribution is f(x)=1/(b-a), which is here f(x)=1/(k-0).

So we have f(x)=1/A

The density function of a [normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg6kD.png) ( because its hard to right here, the variables are associated like this ...~N(µ,, σ^2) )

The thing that i don't understand is how can the random variable X be in the arguments of the normal distribution, I'm used to have just a number and fill the numbers in the equation. And second thing, I don't really get the conditional transformation.[

Comment: It happens that one can solve (b) without solving (a) since $X=kU$ with $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Y=X+Z$ with $Z$ standard normal independent of $U$, hence $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=\mathrm{cov}(kU,kU+Z)=k^2\mathrm{var}(U)=\frac1{12}k^2$, which yields $k=\pm\sqrt{12B}$.

Comment: the equation that I remember about covariance is Cov(X, Y) = E(XY) − E(X)E(Y). But I'll see if both our answers are the same. I don't remember seeing your equation in my book

Comment: Did's point is that one can write down a r.v. $Y$ which is distributed as $N(x,1)$ when conditioned on $X=x$ by adding $X$ to $N(0,1)$ r.v. which is independent of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf of $Y$ is obtained by taking the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ and marginalizing $X$ out. That is:

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx.$$

The joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is the product of the conditional pdf $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ and the pdf of $X$, $f_X$. (If this seems weird to you, it is basically analogous to the familiar identity $P(A \cap B)=P(A \mid B) P(B)$.) That is:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y|x) f_X(x).$$

You have these two pdfs, so with this and some calculus you can do part 1. Once you have the joint pdf you can compute the covariance with some more calculus, so you can do part 2.

The one thing you seem to be having trouble reading is the conditional pdf. The problem is trying to tell you that $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$, for each fixed $x$, is the pdf of a normal r.v. with mean $x$ and variance $1$.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, ill try this out !

Comment: Ok, I think i can easily find the $f_X(x)$ , but the conditional part is where i get lost

Comment: @Lalous Let's say $n_{\mu,\sigma^2}$ is the pdf of a normal r.v. with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=n_{x,1}(y)$. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Yeah, i understand that the mean takes the value of x, but the variance stays 1. But i'm trying to put that in an equation. the first thing that comes in mind, is i have to sum every pdf for all the different x.

Comment: @Lalous In order to get what? The pdf of $Y$? That's exactly what I said above.

Comment: Yes i need the pdf of Y, you helped me alot here,you reminded me about the identity you used, i totaly forgot about it. But to go further now in the problem. I know the pdf of a normal distribution, i linked it as attachment when u click on "normal distribution" in the question. But then there is $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ that i need to figure out. I have a better understanding of what it means, but i still need to develop it, so i can multiply it with $f_{X}(x)$ and then integrate.

Comment: As I said, $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=n_{x,1}(y)$. You know what $n_{x,1}$ looks like already.

Comment: So i just replace the $\mu$ in the pdf of a normal r.v. with x and the $\sigma$ with 1? thats it ?

Comment: To get $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$, yes. But to get $f_Y(y)$, you need to multiply that with $f_X(x)$ and integrate over $x$. (It looks like the result of this is not an elementary function.)

Comment: Another way to proceed would be to follow Did's hint: $Y=X+Z$ where $X$ is $U(0,k)$ and $Z$ is $N(0,1)$ and independent of $X$. Therefore $f_Y=f_X*f_Z$ where $*$ denotes convolution.

Comment: Ok thank you alot, i finaly get it, i was thinking way too far, it was that simple...It happens when i do too much exercices at the same time. I'm not really familiar with Did's hint, so i'll stick with what i started with

Comment: Er, no, you should have $f_Y(y)=C \int_0^k e^{-(x-y)^2/2} dx$, where $C$ is some constant. You won't be able to actually compute this integral, except in terms of the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ or alternately the error function $\operatorname{erf}$.